# Syntax of UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

While running the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY) AS T1
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY) AS T2
LIMIT 1;
```

I get

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'UNION

I can't understand what is the error here

Comment: All queries participating in a `UNION`, `EXCEPT`, or `INTERSECT` (except for the last one) are called "combinable queries". Combinable queries don't accept LIMIT or OFFSET. If you need to limit their result sets, include them as subqueries -- either by enclosing them in parenthesis or as table expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html),

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:

```
(SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY) AS T1
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY) AS T2
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are using ORDER BY in both parts of union (SQL Server does not allow this). Try removing and / or ordering the final result set